# How to build QT QML / Quick Application using WAF?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, waf

I'm trying to build a QT Quick application using WAF. However, it looks like WAF doesn't know what to do with .qml files.

I can build a QT Widget application in WAF using: https://waf.io/apidocs/tools/qt5.html

```
def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_cxx qt5')

def configure(conf):
    conf.load('compiler_cxx qt5')

def build(bld):
    bld(
            features = 'qt5 cxx cxxprogram',
            uselib   = 'QT5CORE QT5GUI QT5OPENGL QT5SVG',
            source   = 'main.cpp textures.qrc aboutDialog.ui',
            target   = 'window',
    )
```

But trying to modify the above for a QT Quick App, by say adding the .qml file to source causes the program to fail to compile due to .qml being unrecognized.

Does anyone know how to do this? I know WAF supports '@extensions'. But I'd rather not have to re-create QT's QML build system in WAF if possible. If that even is possible.

---

If it helps, at the end of the day what I want to do is use the '-platform webgl' feature to get a QT Quick Web Page up that can run my native C++ .dll's (Making WebAssembly out of the question).

Comment: Try adding the QML files to a `qrc` instead of your project file.

Comment: I'm not using a .pro file should I be? Normally I can get waf to build without using the .pro file.

Comment: I ment your WAF project file

Comment: maybe you can look into git://git.ardour.org/ardour/